# g2o conflicts with opencv on /g2o-master/g2o/examples/ba/ba_demo.cpp?

Tags: opencv, g2o

**When I test g2o on /g2o-master/g2o/examples/ba/ba_demo.cpp, CMakeList.txt is as follwing:**

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV 2.4 REQUIRED )
LIST( APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules )
SET( G2O_ROOT /usr/local/include/g2o )
FIND_PACKAGE( G2O REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE( CSparse REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${G2O_INCLUDE_DIR} ${CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR} )
include_directories( "/usr/include/eigen3" )
SET( G2O_LIBS ${CSPARSE_LIBRARY} g2o_core g2o_stuff
g2o_solver_csparse g2o_types_slam3d
g2o_csparse_extension g2o_opengl_helper
g2o_solver_cholmod g2o_types_sba)
FIND_PACKAGE( Cholmod REQUIRED )
message(STATUS " Cholmod = " ${CHOLMOD_LIBRARY} )
message(STATUS " Cholmod = " ${CSPARSE_LIBRARY} )
ADD_EXECUTABLE(ba_demo ba_demo.cpp)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CHOLMOD_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ba_demo ${G2O_LIBS} ${CHOLMOD_LIBRARY} ***${OpenCV_LIBS}*** )
```

Note that ${OpenCV_LIBS} on the last line.

run ba_demo, there is error :
"*** Error in `../bin/ba_demo': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000007b9320 ***
Aborted (core dumped)".

is there anything wrong with my code?